# esper old event 1 with .win:time or length property

Tags: esper

In esper when i am trying to print old events using .win:length or time window property then i am getting only one old and one new event.How is this possible?
And while using time_batch and length_batch , I am getting expected result.e

query is :
select irstream * from StockEvent.win:length(5)

Output snapshot:
[Output snapshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYFTT.png)

Comment: Suggest to clean up the questions as "output snapshot" isn't part of the query and should it be

Comment: Also make sure the code is looking at the whole array that Esper delivers

Answer (score 0):

Yup, expected, as a length-window is a truly sliding window (and not just another batch window). The "Processing Model" chapter of the Esper documentation is a best place to learn how sliding windows work. Few other systems offer sliding windows.